# Some explanation on the resolvent of matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), the resolvent of A is
$$R(t; \mathbf{A}) \equiv \frac{\mathbf{I}}{t\mathbf{\mathbf{I} } -\mathbf{A} } = \frac{\mathrm{adj}(t\mathbf{I} -\mathbf{A}) }{p(t)}  ~,$$
where $p(t)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Are this formula always valid? Maybe, must matrix $A$ be invertible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $R(t,A)=(tI-A)^{-1}$ (no fraction notations for matrices). The formula is valid for all $t\in\mathbb{C}$ that are *not* eigenvalues of $A$, i.e. when the matrix $tI-A$ is invertible (equvalently $p(t)\ne 0$).

Comment: It's a special case of $B^{-1}=(\det B)^{-1}{\rm adj}(B)$ with $B=tI-A$.